# Internet connection dies when new AP is connected

Tags: wireless, hp, access-point

We've been trying to set up a network of WiFi access points at our organization.

The current set-up is as follows:

3 access points connected to a network controller via a switch.
The APs have radios enabled for 2.4GHz and 5GHz frequencies.

The access points are HP 525-WW devices. The controller is an HP 850.

Now, whenever we connect another AP to the switch, with an enabled and configured radio, the whole network dies, including both WiFi and wired connections to the controller.

The access points all reboot, start initialising, then flash the LED indicating an error with the radio, and after a few seconds start initialising again, then indicate radio error, etc.

When the new AP is disconnected, everything goes back to normal after a few seconds.

I'm not a network engineer, just a system administrator, so I'm not overly familiar with network engineering. We've been trying to resolve this issue for days, but have been unable to.

I can provide any extra information if needed.

Edit 1: On further testing, adding a new AP works when connected directly to a switch, but fails as described when connected via a PoE adapter.

Edit 2: Device models - Switch: HP-2530-8G-PoEP; Adapter: Powerdsine 3001G

Comment: What are the IP addresses of all devices?  If I had to guess, your new AP has a duplicate address.

Comment: On further testing, adding a new AP works when connected directly to a switch, but fails as described when connected via a PoE adapter. It doesn't seem like a conflicting IP. Editing this to the post as well.

Comment: What kind of switch?  Is it PoE also?  Have you tried another PoE adapter?

Comment: its may be wireless interference so you may need to configure each access point in different channel , for example if you use 2.4 band you may use ch 3 , 6 , 11  for your APs

Comment: @RonTrunk The switch is PoE. The PoE adapter works when only one AP is connected, but when a second AP is connected with another PoE adapter, it fails. When either is connected without the other, it works. We have several identical PoE adapters and have tried switching them around.

Comment: What are the models of the switch and adapters?

Comment: @RonTrunk Switch: HP-2530-8G-PoEP; Adapter: Powerdsine 3001G

Comment: @Gadeliow Tried this, did not help.

Comment: Can you console to the HP switch?  Do you see any status messages when you connect the AP?

Comment: It sounds like you overload the power supply on the switch. Just because you have so many PoE ports doesn't mean you can use them all for PoE. There should be a command in the switch to show the power status.

Comment: @RonMaupin That actually makes a lot of sense. The switch has a PoE capacity of 67W according to the specs, and the power rating for the APs is 12.9W, which gives just about enough power for 5 APs. At some point we briefly got 5 APs running for a few minutes, after which everything died again. This could very well be the reason. I'll definitely look into this when I get into office tomorrow, thank you very much!

Comment: @RonMaupin Actually, that is not possible. We are using PoE adapters connected to a power outlet to provide PoE to the APs. The switch only handles the ethernet connection.

Comment: It really does sound like a power issue - are you *sure* that the APs are not drawing any power from the switch? I understand they shouldn't - but aren't they? As RonMaupin mentioned there should be a command on the switch that shows you how much power is drawn by each port. Something similar to "show power inline" on a Cisco switch. Or a command to disable PoE (per port, or for the whole switch, if it is not needed on other ports).

Comment: @RonMaupin You were right, it was a power issue. Even though the PoE adapter was connected to a power supply, it still drew power from the switch for some reason. Disabling PoE on the switch solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should either write your own answer and accept it, or I can write an answer for you to accept. Unless the question has an accepted answer, it will pop up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your symptoms point to an overloaded power supply on the switch. PoE switches, especially low-end models, can usually only handle a few PoE devices. There should be some power commands in the switch to show you the power status, and allow you to enable/disable PoE on the ports.

Per your comment, it was a power problem, and disabling PoE on the switch solved the problem.